# Layout difficulties. Keep text to right of view until edge of parent

Tags: android

I have the next bad design for Android:

[image]

I need to keep `More infos` with the icon to the right of the black text. If `Item 1 of 1` will be a longer string, it'll push the icon+text to the right. My problem which I can't figure out is if the left text it too long to fit in one line, i'd like it for `More infos` to be pushed until the right edge of its parent and stay there and the left black text should jump to a new line.

But this is not HTML for it to act like that ! :) Any ideas on how I could accomplish this ?

I'm really thinking of asking the designer to change the design.

**EDIT**

What I've done for it to look like above:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>

<!--TEXT-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_form_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/app_spacing_x0_5"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/app_spacing_x3"
    android:textColor="@color/app_black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_tiny" />

<!--VIEW DETAILS-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_view_details_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/list_item_form_text"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/list_item_form_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_camera"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/app_spacing_x0_3"
    android:text="@string/f_form_front_view_details" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share what you've already tried?

Comment: Sure. See the edit... It's really not a good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with a `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="test"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="123444"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The key is having the Linear Layout with `wrap_content` and the first view with `weight=1` and `width=0dp`

Comment: It looks like this if I do that .... http://puu.sh/vadsq/4740132f82.png :(

Comment: is the `linearlayout` with wrap_content?

Comment: hah! no, it wasn't ! ... What a dummy ! (i'm talking about myself). Yeah ... this is the correct solution !! Thank you ! I wonder if this "hack-ish" approach is acceptable on all OSs.

Comment: No problem. I am not sure what you mean by ` I wonder if this "hack-ish" approach is acceptable on all OSs` as it is not a hack-ish solution. This is the right solution. Also in the future, always try to use `LinearLayout` or ` FramLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`, as they have better performance, since `RelativeLayout` has 2 draw operations :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
<!--TEXT-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_form_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:text="Long long long long text Long long long long text"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/list_item_view_details_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

<!--VIEW DETAILS-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_view_details_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minWidth="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/list_item_form_text"
    android:text="More infos"/>
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: And what is `long long...` text is very short? `list_item_view_details_btn` will be aligned with right edge, which is not what OP needs.

Comment: If you already have it written, try it with a smaller length text ... i'm guessing the More infos will align to the right of the parent and not to the right of the left side text, no ?